# How to register RestController with RefreshScope after Refresh

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-config

we are using Spring Cloud Config with our Spring Boot/MVC application.

Lately we tried something tricky, like the following code...

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
@ConditionalOnProperty("useCase1.enabled")
public class UseCase1Controller {     
   @RequestMapping(path = "/v1/doSomething")
   public String doSomething() {
   }
}
```

and under the 'spring-cloud-config' I have the following 'app1.yml'...

```
useCase1.enabled=true
```

Now with this configuration everything is fine and works perfectly, now if I change the property at 'Spring Cloud Config Server/app1.yml' and trigger 'actuator/refresh' at 'Config Server' and 'App1 - Boot application' to 'useCase1.enabled=false' UseCase1Controller disabled...

The problem is if I start the application with 'useCase1.enabled=false' then change to true and refresh, I guess as expected RestController is not registered (I guess annotation scan happens at the start of application context and not for the beans initialized later)...

So my question how/can I register my RestController after the refresh?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported and it seems that the spring team has no intention to support it in the future. See related issue [https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1645](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1645#issuecomment-653070180)